# How to free data malloc()'d inside a loop?

Tags: c, loops, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

void reverse_print_list(Node *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        return;

    print_list(head->next);
    printf("%d ", head->data);
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->data = rand() % 100;
    head->next = NULL;

    Node *temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new_node->data = rand() % 100;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        temp->next = new_node;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp = head;
    printf("Original list : \n");
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");

    reverse_print_list(head);

    free(head);
    free(temp);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, inside the for loop in main(), I am dynamically allocating memory for new nodes of a linked-list and attaching every newly created node to the last node in the list. But this seems like it would result in a memory leak since I am not freeing those nodes at the end of the loop as I need those nodes to exist outside of the loop. How can I free the nodes I have created inside the for loop? Running another loop starting from `head` to save all the nodes' addresses and then running another loop to manually free() all of those addresses seems tedious. Is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you need/want to free the nodes inside the `for` loop? They are all linked into the list so you can't free the memory and then expect to be able to access them after the loop (which you do need). You can `free` the memory at a later time by traversing the list again.

Comment: Q: "How to free data malloc()'d inside a loop?" A: "running another loop to manually free() all of those addresses" You just do not need the loop in the middle. Maybe I do not get the three loop approach. If it seems tedious but works then show it. It will be easier to understad what you mean and to point out how to make less tedious.

Comment: To free the full memory you allocated, you can use a recursive function like the one you you to reverse print from head. Once memory is allocated somewhere in a c program, it stay allocated until it is explicitly freed or the program exits . To prevent memory leak, you just have to be able to free what has been allocated when it become useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the head node and replace `head` with its successor. Repeat until `head` becomes empty. Please note, you must backup the `next` pointer before calling free().

```
int main()
{
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->data = rand() % 100;
    head->next = NULL;

    ... build and print your list ...

    while (head)
    {
       Node * remainingChain = head->next;
       free(head);
       head = remainingChain;
    }
    return 0;
}
```